# How to add long text and data to x tick labels using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, x-axis

I am trying to replicate the bar plot as shown bellow.

Here is an example of the data frame. Where the y variable is *tasa* and the x variable is *year*, and the number showed in the text of each x tick label is *inscripciones*.

```
df <- structure(list(year = c("2018", "2019"), inscripciones = c(3038910, 3680696), tasa = c(88.9528707645112, 104.692208214133)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = tasa)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.4, stat = "identity", fill="orange")+
  geom_text(aes(year, tasa + 5, label = round(tasa,2), fill = NULL), size=4)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 110, by = 10))+
  theme_bw()
```

How can I add these long text including information from the dataframe to the x tick labels?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your data & plot combination are not reproducible. I renamed `annoh` as `year` then create the plot `p`.

Then,`scale_x_discrete` with "\n" strings works when you want to skip lines;

[image]

```
long_text_1 <-  'Gün, senden ışık alsa\n da bir renge bürünse;\n
Ay, secde edip çehrene,\n yerlerde sürünse;\n
Her şey silinip\n kayboluyorken nazarımdan,\n
Yalnız o yeşil\n gözlerinin nuru görünse...'

long_text_2 <- 'Ruhun mu ateş,\nyoksa o gözler mi alevden?\n
Bilmem bu yanardağ\n ne biçim korla tutuştu?\n
Pervane olan kendini\n gizler mi hiç alevden?\n
Sen istedin ondan bu\n gönül zorla tutuştu.'


p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = tasa)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.4, stat = "identity", fill="orange")+
  geom_text(aes(year, tasa + 5, label = round(tasa,2), fill = NULL), size=4)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 110, by = 10))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('2018'=long_text_1,'2019'=long_text_2))
```